# Getting output in the same way as most Stat packages

Tags: time-series

I have been looking at several of the timeseries functions in mathematica, however running a process like ARDL, ARMA, GARCH or ARCH you would be able to get a ANOVA table, with its coefficients and p value, you also in most packages would get R and R^2.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to get ANOVA table when running an ARDL model or a ARCH model. I know it is possible with linear model fit, but I am not able to get it when using any other models.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way. We will illustrate this using the following example.

```
data = Table[{3 + i + RandomReal[{-3, 7}], i + RandomReal[{-2, 5}]}, {i, 1, 20}];

model = LinearModelFit[data, x, x]

(* ANOVA table *)
model["ANOVATable"]
```

> $\begin{array}{l|lllll}
>  \text{} & \text{DF} & \text{SS} & \text{MS} & \text{F-Statistic} & \text{P-Value} \\
> \hline
>  x & 1 & 585.43 & 585.43 & 55.8679 & \text{6.360782869783599$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-7} \\
>  \text{Error} & 18 & 188.619 & 10.4788 & \text{} & \text{} \\
>  \text{Total} & 19 & 774.049 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
> \end{array}$

```
(* Unformatted entries from the table *)
model["ANOVATableEntries"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 585.43, 585.43, 55.8679, 6.36078*10^-7}, {18, 188.619, 10.4788}, {19, 774.049}}
> ```

```
(* p-values from the table *)
model["ANOVATablePValues"]
```

> ```
> {6.36078*10^-7}
> ```

```
(* response mean divided by the estimated standard deviation *)
model["CoefficientOfVariation"]
```

> ```
> 0.263479
> ```

Comment: Thats great, would you be able to do that with an ARmodel instead of the linear model fit?